# DictUnifier App is working on MacOS Catalina

Tags: macos

I have recently updated my MacBookPro with MacOS Catalina. DictUnifier App is working but once I drag the ifo, tar.bz2 file onto the DictUnifier App, the app getting close automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Someone that maintains [this](https://github.com/bhagyas/osx-sinhalese-dictionary) repo, which includes the DictUnifier App, seems to have updated the app with support for Catalina.

Give it try